# Total energy of a causal impulse response (tricky integral)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, z-transform

The total energy of a causal impulse response is given by:

$$
\begin{align}
E
&= {1 \over 2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left|{H(e^{i\omega})}\right|^2d\omega
\\
&= {1 \over 2 \pi i} \oint H(z)H(z^{-1})z^{-1}dz
\end{align}
$$

Where $z = e^{-i\omega}$ and $H(z)$ is given by:

$$
H(z) = {b_0 + b_1 z^{-1} + b_2 z^{-2} \over 1 + a_1 z^{-1} + a_2 z^{-2}}
$$

Apparently the determination of this integral in the z-domain is known, does anyone know what it is?

Comment: I think you've got a couple of typos there. The second integral should be a contour integral over the unit circle, not over $[-\pi,\pi]$, and where it says "Where $\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i\omega}$" I think it's meant to say "Where $z=\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i\omega}$"? As to the solution: Do you know the residue theorem?

Comment: @joriki, thanks I've made those corrections, you were spot on. It's 20 years since I did complex analysis at uni and I'm a bit rusty to say the least. I don't know the residue theorem.

Comment: @joriki, just had a look at the residue theorem, so do I need to apply partial fraction expansion to $H(z)\bar{H(z{-1})z^{-1}}$ to get it in the right form to apply this theorem would you say?

Comment: Exactly. Note that the poles of $H(z)$ and of $H(z^{-1})$ are reciprocals of each other, so unless they're on the unit circle (in which case the integral would be undefined), two are inside and two are outside (and $z^{-1}$ contributes a third pole at $z=0$, with residue $b_0b_2/a_2$). I don't see any way to make use of the special structure of the problem beyond that.

Comment: @joriki, thank you, you've given me exactly the help I was looking for. I'd mark it as the answer if you posted an answer with "use the residue theorem" in it :-)

Comment: OK, I posted my comment as an answer. Glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the residue theorem. Note that the poles of $H(z)$ and of $H(z^{−1})$ are reciprocals of each other, so unless they're on the unit circle (in which case the integral would be undefined), two are inside and two are outside (and $z^{−1}$ contributes a third pole at $z=0$, with residue $b_0b_2/a_2$). I don't see any way to make use of the special structure of the problem beyond that.